# flutter 2 ,can build an iPhone app (ios) without an Apple device?

Tags: flutter

I heard that (flutter 2) after the new update, you can build an iPhone app (ios) without an Apple device. Is this correct? If this is true, how can I do that?

Comment: You don’t have a chance in hell to build a working app without an actual device. There are eight different devices on my desk right now.

Comment: to build an iOS app (with your flutter project), you need XCode, which is only available on Mac OS, so you need a Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can write an iPhone-compatible app without Apple device but you will need a Mac to test, build and push it to the App Store. Nothing changed about that with Flutter 2

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't build without a MacOS.

However, you can use an external tool like Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI), a tool that lets you connect to a MacOS machine to test your app and configure Xcode.

You can install Odevio by checking the website https://www.odevio.com

Follow the doc here (https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html) to link your Apple developper account with Odevio and more.